# How to write config.ru for Rack static site?

Tags: ruby, rack

My `config.ru`

```
require 'rack'
use Rack::Static, :root => '_site'
```

But when I run `rackup` I get an error

> /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:133:in `to_app': missing run or map statement (RuntimeError)

I want to the host the files in the folder `_site_` at the root URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `config.ru` is that it's missing a `run` command, and you always need one. As matt suggested, you could use a `Rack::File` middleware.

But if you want to keep the `Rack::Static` capabilities, then you could do something like this that serves an index file and have the `Rack::Static` middleware in front of it, to serve any file from `_site_`.

```rb
use Rack::Static,
  :urls => ["/"],
  :root => "_site_"

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200,
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html',
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400'
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Rack::Static`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Static.html) is a piece of middleware that uses [`Rack::File`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/File.html), which is an app. If all you’re doing is serving static files, you can just run `Rack::File` directly:

```
# note 'run' not 'use'
run Rack::File.new('_site')
```

Comment: This runs, but doesn't find my `index.html`s. I would like requests to eg. `/CV` to redirect to `/CV/` and then be served `_site/CV/index.html`.